# Insert the data of richtextbox into existing xml in c# linq

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have a xml like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<assessment xmlns="http://xml.thinkcentral.com/pub/xml/hsp/assessment" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:tia="http://xml.thinkcentral.com/pub/xml/hsp/tia" xmlns:tibase="http://xml.thinkcentral.com/pub/xml/hsp/tibase" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xml.thinkcentral.com/pub/xml/hsp/assessment http://xml.thinkcentral.com/pub/xml1_2_6/hsp_assessment.xsd" isbn="9780547660455" buid="NA12_AG_G01CH01A" title="Chapter 1 Test Form A" num_questions="24" num_sections="1" type="Basal" intervenable="true" duration="P5Y" pausable="false" scramble="false">
  <test_section id="1" name="Chapter 1 Test Form A" index="1">
    <aaa testitem_id="NA12_AG_G01CH01A_01" template="hsp_testitem_mc1.xslt" id="1" bankable="true">
      <tia:multipleChoiceTestItem total-points="1" questionType="Multiple Choice" sample="false" version_label="1.0">
        <tia:directions>
          <tia:tiDirectionLine>
            <tia:textBody></tia:textBody>
          </tia:tiDirectionLine>
          <tia:address>Richtextbox Data</tia:address>
        </tia:directions>
      </tia:multipleChoiceTestItem>
    </aaa>
    <aaa testitem_id="NA12_AG_G01CH01A_02" template="hsp_testitem_mc1.xslt" id="2" bankable="true">
      <tia:multipleChoiceTestItem total-points="1" questionType="Multiple Choice" sample="false" version_label="1.0">
        <tia:directions>
          <tia:tiDirectionLine>
            <tia:textBody></tia:textBody>
          </tia:tiDirectionLine>
          <tia:address>Richtextbox Data</tia:address>
        </tia:directions>
      </tia:multipleChoiceTestItem>
    </aaa>
  </test_section>
</assessment>
```

I have to insert the the data according to the id of the aaa element.

```
<aaa testitem_id="NA12_AG_G01CH01A_01" template="hsp_testitem_mc1.xslt" id="1" bankable="true">
<aaa testitem_id="NA12_AG_G01CH01A_02" template="hsp_testitem_mc1.xslt" id="2"bankable="true">
```

if id="1" then data of ritchtextbox will be insert into tia:address node.

i am using the following code.

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"d:\file.xml");


      XNamespace ns = XNamespace.Get("http://tia.com");           

    var result=  (from ele in doc.Descendants("aaa")
       where ((string)ele.Attribute("id")) == "1"
       select ele.Element(ns+"address")).FirstOrDefault(); 




        if (result != null)
        {
            result.Value = richTextBox1.Text;

            doc.Save(@"d:\file.xml");
        }
        MessageBox.Show("done");

    }
```

its not working. how i do that?

Comment: which techno ? what did you tried ? what errors did you get ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of al, the XML markup you have posted is not valid. I think the easiest way to read/write an XML document is `Linq-XML`. You have to import  `System.Xml.Linq` namespace to use [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387063.aspx) class and its method. Take a look at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) article.

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"c:\file.xml");

var result = (from ele in doc.Descendants("aaa")
                where ((string)ele.Attribute("id")) == "1"
                select ele.Element("address")).FirstOrDefault();

if (result != null)
{
    result.Value = richTextBox1.Text;
    doc.Save(@"c:\file.xml");
}
```

XML document should be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <aaa id="1">
    <address>Hello World</address>
  </aaa>
  <aaa id="2">
    <address>
      write text of ritchtextbox here</address>
  </aaa>
</root>
```

EDIT:

In OP, XML markup has some issues and I've fixes the markup (added namespace).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<aaa testitem_id="chapter1" template="hsp_testitem_mc1.xslt" id="1" bankable="true" xmlns:tia="http://tia.com">
  <tia:multipleChoiceTestItem total-points="1" questionType="Multiple Choice" sample="false" version_label="1.0">
    <tia:directions>
      <tia:tiDirectionLine>
        <tia:textBody />
      </tia:tiDirectionLine>
      <tia:address>I have to edited here.(Richtextbox data)</tia:address>
    </tia:directions>
  </tia:multipleChoiceTestItem>
</aaa>
```

Code to find `<tia:address>` and replace its value.

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(file);

XNamespace ns = XNamespace.Get("http://tia.com");

var result = (from ele in doc.Descendants(ns + "address")
                select ele).SingleOrDefault();

if (result != null)
{
    result.Value = richTextBox1.Text;
    doc.Save(file);
}
```

EDIT : After changes made by OP in opening post.

```
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(file);
    //Change the namespace
    XNamespace ns = XNamespace.Get("http://xml.thinkcentral.com/pub/xml/hsp/tia");
    var result = (
                 from ele in doc.Descendants(ns + "multipleChoiceTestItem")
                 where ele.Parent.Attribute("id").Value == "1"
                 select 
                    ele.Descendants(ns+"address").FirstOrDefault()
                 ).FirstOrDefault();

    if (result != null)
    {
        result.Value = "World";
        doc.Save(file);
    }
```

Comment: when i debug this code  the var gives Null. where i am wrong.

Comment: it works when there is one<aaa> element. but when there are multipile <aaa>element then it returns null.how can i do?  there is no search criteria for id.

Comment: I am using  var result=  (from ele in doc.Descendants("aaa")
           where ((string)ele.Attribute("id")) == "1"
           select ele.Element(ns+"address")).FirstOrDefault();       but it not works. it gives null.

Comment: Thanks a lot It now fully working according to my requirement.